# Android Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT unit

Tags: android, sensors, light

Does anybody knows the unit of the return value of Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT on Android ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in SI lux units (m/s<sup>2</sup>).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : it seems to be Lux unit : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lux

If you want to know everything :

> 1 lx = 1 lm/m^2 = 1 cd·sr·m^-2

Where : lx = lux, lm = lumen, cd = candela, sr = steradian

Comment: Oh, I wasn't clear enough. I mean, what is the unity of event.values[0] in onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event). Is it candela per square meter ?

Comment: JRL told you it's `SI lux units m/s²` (je savais pas que tu étais sur ce site :p)